# Displaying unsorted List's top 20 items

Tags: c#, list

I have an unsorted `List<WordCount>`

```
class WordCount
{
string word;
int count;
}
```

And now I must display the top 20 items in descending order of count. How could I code this efficiently? Currently I would set a minimum integer of -1 (all `count` >= 1) and do a for loop of 20 iterations with a foreach loop inside.  This is an issue though because the last few elements in the `List` could have `count` of 1 while the top few may have an element with `count` 1 so now I am stuck on the pseudocode for this implementation for displaying them in order.

I CANNOT use LINQ or any other things other than the methods for `List` class. I personally think I must accomplish this feat using `Sort()` and `CompareTo()` somehow. This is meant to be a brain twister and that is the reason why it has to be done using the given restriction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
List<WordCount> counts = new List<WordCount>();
//Fill the list
var result = counts.OrderBy(c => c.Count).Take(20);
```

Descending order:

```
var result = counts.OrderByDescending(c => c.Count).Take(20);
```

### [Edit] Using self-made methods:

Here's a solution without any .NET method. First sort the list using an algorithm, in this case I used the Bubblesort (not effeicient for larger collections). Then I take the 20 first element from the sorted result:

```
public class WordCount
{
    public string Word { get; set; }
    public int CharCount { get; set; }
}

public List<WordCount> SortList(List<WordCount> list)
{
    WordCount temp;
    for (int i = list.Count -1; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < list.Count -1; j++)
        {
            if(list[j].CharCount < list[j+1].CharCount)
            {
                temp = list[j];
                list[j] = list[j+1];
                list[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}

public List<WordCount> TakeNItems(int n, List<WordCount> list)
{
    List<WordCount> temp = new List<WordCount>();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        temp.Add(list[i]);
    return temp;
}

//Usage:
var result = SortList(counts);
result = TakeNItems(20, result);
```

### [Edit2] Using Sort() / CompareTo()

Yes, it is also possible using `Sort()` and `CompareTo()`. This requieres a couple of changes to your class because when you try to use Sort() now, you'll get an `InvalidOperationException`. This is because the WordCount class does not implement the `IComparable` interface. Implementing the interface means you'll have to override the `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` methods and provide your own comparer. Here's a simple implementation based on the [**List(T).Sort Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public class WordCount : IComparable<WordCount>
{
    public string Word { get; set; }
    public int CharCount { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        WordCount wc = obj as WordCount;
        return wc == null ? false : Equals(wc);
    }

    public int CompareTo(WordCount wc)
    {
        //Descending
        return wc == null ? 1 : wc.CharCount.CompareTo(CharCount);

        //Ascending
        //return wc == null ? 1 : CharCount.CompareTo(wc.CharCount);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return CharCount;
    }

    public bool Equals(WordCount wc)
    {
        return wc == null ? false : CharCount.Equals(wc.CharCount);
    }
}

//Usage:
List<WordCount> counts = new List<WordCount>();
//Fill the list
counts.Sort();
```

And for the limit of 20 items you can write your own extension method which would basically do the same as the **[Enumerable.Take Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> TakeN<T>(this List<T> list, int n)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            yield return list[i];
    }
}

//Usage:
List<WordCount> counts = new List<WordCount>();
//Fill the list with 10000 items and call TakeN()

IEnumerable<WordCount> smallList = counts.TakeN(20);
//Or
counts = counts.TakeN(20).ToList();
```

Hope this clarifies it all! ;)

Comment: `in descending order`

Comment: @Abbas I am not familiar with => but I think that is LINQ, yes? I am not allowed to use LINQ.

Comment: Yes, this is LinQ with lambda-expressions. You did not mention that you weren't allowed to use this.. :)

Comment: @HarrisCalvin, you should explain why you can't in your question.

Comment: @Abbas I cannot use LINQ for this..it has to be using the built-in methods for List or pure algorithm.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko It is a restriction imposed by the question. This isn't for real-life use but it is a brain teaser.

Comment: @Abbas thank you and this should work. Could I also make an implementation using CompareTo() and Sort() method?

Comment: Check the second edit, I explained everything and added code as an example. :)

Answer (score 0):

The most straight-forward solution, using System.Linq:

```
var words = new List<WordCount>();
var result = from w in words orderby w.count descending select w.word;
result = result.Take(20);
```

This is most convenient and clear solution, so when possible use Linq. Also the result will be an `IEnumerable<WordCount>`, so compiler can do optimizations such as lazy enumeration, not calculating all elements until asked for them.

Comment: Check my answer, that was my solution too but apparently he's not allowed or won't use LinQ...

Comment: Why don't you use `yield`? the simplest solution would be use selection sort (select biggest one), yield return enumerator, and then filter enumerator in TakeNItems.

Comment: You're probably right, I was only giving him an example of how he could achieve the same without LinQ. It most likely is not the most efficient solution, but it does the trick. :)