# Displaying and unsorted list in sorted top 20 manner with CompareTo

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I want to display the top 20 items in the List d. I have one implementation here: [Displaying unsorted List's top 20 items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20119639/displaying-unsorted-lists-top-20-items)

Instead of using bubble-sort, now I want to implement using the Sort() and CompareTo() built-in method in the `List` Class. I am unsure of how to use the CompareTo() and Sort() methods even after reading on MSDN an example.

Summary of problem:

I have an unsorted List

```
class WordCount
{
string word;
int count;
}
```

**And now I must display the top 20 items in descending order of count.
How do I use the Sort() or CompareTo() methods to do this?** I am confused by the syntax or how in order to use Sort() you need a defaule comparer (what on earth is that?) and CompareTo() has to have strange code written for it....Overall I am just confused on how to use Sort() and CompareTo() to do sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var top20 = list.OrderByDescending(x=>x.count).Take(20).ToList();
```

You may want another kind of result like this:

```
var top20 = list.Take(20).OrderByDescending(x=>x.count).ToList();
```

If the latter is what you want, you should go for it. Because you just want 20 first items. Using `Sort` method will sort the whole list and you also still have to use `Take` then or use it directly in a `for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) ...`

### UPDATE

For the use of `Sort` and an `IComparer`:

```
public class DescendingComparer : IComparer<WordCount> {
  public int Compare(WordCount x, WordCount y) {
    return -Comparer<int>.Default.Compare(x.count, y.count);
  }
}
```

Now you can use the `Sort` like this:

```
list.Sort(new DescendingComparer());
//you should use the `Take(20)` to get the top or use a for like this:
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
  //list[i]...
}
```

Comment: but what if I don't want to use LINQ and I want to use Sort() and CompareTo()? People in the last post of mine suggested LINQ so I really don't want the same solution suggested again...

Comment: @HarrisCalvin why are you dead-set against using Linq? It is a terrific feature for scenarios like this.

Comment: @HarrisCalvin see my update and let me know if it's what you want.

Comment: @KingKing you have the order of your `Take()` and `OrderByDescending()` calls switched, as is, it will take the first twenty and then order them.

Comment: @ledbutter for `LINQ` usage, I provided 2 codes for the user to select, that's Take first then order and order first then Take. I doubt that the OP wants the latter

Comment: @HarrisCalvin you have to define the `count` as `public`, the same for the other.

Comment: @KingKing Ahh yes I made the WordCount class public and that solved the issue. Thank you sooooo much because I never would have understood this on my own.

Comment: @HarrisCalvin you're welcome, anyway the only advantage of `Sort` over `LINQ` in sorting elements of a list is it modifies the list directly and it's convenient if we don't need to use some custom IComparer.